# Exclude items from navbar toggle

Tags: bootstrap-4, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How do i exclude `['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],` from collapse on bootstrap 4?

```
use yii\bootstrap4\NavBar;
use yii\bootstrap4\Nav;

NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'NavBar Test',
    'options' => [
       'class' => 'navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm text-center',
    ],
]);
echo Nav::widget([
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
    ],
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
]);
NavBar::end();
```

Basically i want it to work like this https://www.codeply.com/p/CvIXtKJda9  Where not all items collapse on smaller screens.